# Key event handling

Tags: c++, qt

Currently I want to handle basic key handling; e.g. if key is pressed, do this. However, should this have its own class or be done within a single function? Qt has a means of recording key events, but I know not how to proceed. I could have:

```
void keyPrHandle(QKeyEvent *Ev)
{
   if (Ev->key() == Qt::Key_G)
       ui->label->setText(Ev->text());
}
```

Else I would have to build a class that handles key events. I don't know how Qt handles key events, nor how I should implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in derived class. Suppose you have QBase and QDerive classes. Then you can reimplement event handlers:

```cpp
void QDerived::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Ev)
{
   if (Ev->key() == Qt::Key_G)
       //do something
   QBase::keyPressEvent(Ev);
}
```

And also in QDerive class:

```cpp
protected:
   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Ev);
```

You can also handle events without subclassing with [event filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).

Answer (score 1):

Every `QWidget` handles key events. Where you should implement the key handling depends on where you do need these. If your whole program should act on key presses you should overload [`keyPressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) in your `QMainWindow`.

Of course, if child widgets are active (like form input widgets), those take up the key handling. This might mean you have to intercept those events as well.

Comment: Only one dialog in my program requires key event handling. Should I still overload keyPressEvent()?

Comment: well, in that particular dialog you probably should. It kind of depends on the specific task you want have. In some cases the `eventFilter` Chernobyl mentioned can be better. But the easiest way would be overriding the `keyPressEvent` in that dialog